# is it safe to delete package files

Tags: package-management

After downloaded, extracted package files from .tar.gz and installed (e.g. using setup.py install or make all), is it safe to delete the extracted files?
Similarly, if I use pip, there is a build directory containing the package files. Is it safe to delete these?
Because they are all over my home directory. If it is safe to delete them, where do the working files go to anyway?  (Like in Windows, they usually go under Programs directory)

Answer (score 0):

After the installation completes you can delete them.

Depending on the package, the files are on different paths on your system like `/usr/lib` `/usr/bin` and so on